# Insert succeeds but the inserted value shows NULL in the back end ms sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have a simple `mvc5` code first application, It has a ms SQL database in the back-end and and a form in the front-end.

While I insert into database via the front end form, it does not generate any error, everything seems OK but when i check the back end database table, then all values in the newly inserted row are showing as `NULL`.

This is my code for model:

```
public class students
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string st_name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Father's Name")]
    public string st_father_name { get; set; }

    public string  st_contact { get; set; }
}
```

This is the View Model class:

```
public class AddStudentViewModel
{
    public students stdntss { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var std = _context.stdnts;
    if (std==null)
    {
        return Content("Nothing Found");
    }
    return View(std);
}


public ActionResult AddStudent()
{

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Insert(students st)
{
    _context.stdnts.Add(st);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Students");
}
```

And finally this is the view:

```
@model school2.ViewModels.AddStudentViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddStudent";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New student's registration form</h2>



@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert","Students"))
{
<div class="form-group">

   @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.stdntss.st_name)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.stdntss.st_name, new { @class="form-control"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.stdntss.st_father_name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.stdntss.st_father_name, new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>


<div class="form-group">

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.stdntss.st_contact)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.stdntss.st_contact, new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Kindly assist me if anyone has any clue?

Comment: First thing: what does `st` have after you submit your form?

Comment: [Guidelines for naming properties for class is Pascal Convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members).  Obviously it's just a guideline, however other developers might be confused why properties are lower cased (e.g. `st_father_name` instead of `StFatherName  `)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to change the POST method to accept the same model as the view.

try changing

```
public ActionResult Insert(students st)
{
    _context.stdnts.Add(st);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Students");
}
```

to

```
  public ActionResult Insert(AddStudentViewModel st)
  {
      _context.stdnts.Add(st.stdntss );
      _context.SaveChanges();
      return RedirectToAction("Index","Students");
  }
```

or changing the model of the form to simply be student.

Comment: It's doesn't *need* to.  Based on the available classes, this is one way to do it, but saying *need* sounds like it's required/the only way when it isn't.

Comment: @Dale_dale12 thank you very much, your technique solved the problem

Comment: @ErikPhilips, good point, I've changed the wording slightly to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

I think that change @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.stdntss.st_name, new { @class="form-control"}). because call Model, @model school2.ViewModels.AddStudentViewModel . Variable default Model.

Comment: Please try to improve the comprehension of your answ er. Read the help pages and try to improve formatting in the future.